# ServiceStack OrmLite create table with [AutoIncrement] fail

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack version="3.9.54" targetFramework="net40" with PostgreSQL.\

When i create table with

```
public class test
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string test_name { get; set; }

}

dbConn.CreateTable<test>(true);

CREATE TABLE test
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  test_name text,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE);
```

But when i create with

```
 public class test
    {
        public string test_name { get; set; }

        [AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }

    }
dbConn.CreateTable<test>(true);
```

Here is table on Postgres

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  test_name text NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (test_name)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

What happen with my id columns. Is it bug ?

Thanks for your help

Tuan Hoang Anh

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some conventions and case-sensitivity at play here. If you change `id` to `Id` it should work

```
public class test
{
    public string test_name { get; set; }

    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
dbConn.CreateTable<test>(true);
```

OrmLite [expects an 'Id' property](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#limitations) to be present and to be the primary key. You can attribute a property with `[PrimaryKey]` if you don't want to use `Id`. However, in this case attributing `id` with `[PrimaryKey]` will attempt to create 2 primary keys since OrmLite can't find an Id field and (I think) defaults the first property it finds to be the primary key (can't find docs/proof to back this up, though)

Comment: It work with 1 [AutoIncrement] but don't work with 2 [AutoIncrement]